# jQuery bind function to parent div but not child anchor and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div, inside of which are a few anchor links:

```
<div id="myDiv">
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|  <a class="myAnc">...</a>  |
|  <a class="myAnc">...</a>  |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

I want to bind a click event to `#myDiv` that calls `myFunction1()` but have `.myAnc` tags call `myFunction2()`.  Using jQuery's `bind`, what happens is that both `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` are called no matter what you click on (the div or the anchor).

How can I make sure that they call on their two separate functions (and only those functions)?

Comment: when u click on anchor, first `unbind` the previous event and then bind with function 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `myFunction2(ev)` call:

```
ev.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("a.myAnc").click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); // prevent DOM event bubbling which will trigger the click of the parent div
});

$("#myDiv").click(function() {
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the solution.  good to know it's called bubbling.  checked the other answer for being one minute earlier

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv, a.myAnc').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent bubbling to #myDiv

   alert('you click  ' + $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".myAnc").bind("click",
                         function()
                         {
                             myFunction2();
                             return false;
                         }
                        );

    }
```

Working demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/NeLsE/